# Bound on variable inside conditional?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have a conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra that is bounded above by a constant, $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{F}] \le C$. Can we deduce that the variable $X$ also is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $X$ have a standard  normal distribution and suppose $X$ is independent of $\mathcal F$. Then the conditional expectation is $0$ and $X$ is not bounded.